# List<T>.addrange() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have property :

```
public List<RequestCheckListDetail> DocumentChecklistMasterList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["DocumentChecklistMasterList"].IsObjectUsable())
            _documentChecklistMasterList = (List<RequestCheckListDetail>)ViewState["DocumentChecklistMasterList"];
        else
            this._documentChecklistMasterList = new List<RequestCheckListDetail>();
        return this._documentChecklistMasterList;
    }

    set { ViewState["DocumentChecklistMasterList"] = value; }
}
```

I am trying to add data to it using another list. However another list has different entity, so i am running loop over first list like:

```
List<RequestCheckListDetail> newList = new List<RequestCheckListDetail>();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (DocumentCheckListMaster item in list)
    {

        newList.Add(new RequestCheckListDetail
        {
            Id = i,
            CheckListMaster = item
        });
        i++;
    }
    this.DocumentChecklistMasterList.AddRange(newList);
```

even if `newList` has items in it, `DocumentChecklistMasterList` always have 0 items.
I have tried following things:

```
List<RequestCheckListDetail> newList = new List<RequestCheckListDetail>();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (DocumentCheckListMaster item in list)
    {

        this.DocumentChecklistMasterList.Add(new RequestCheckListDetail
        {
            Id = i,
            CheckListMaster = item
        });
        i++;
    }


 List<RequestCheckListDetail> newList = new List<RequestCheckListDetail>();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (DocumentCheckListMaster item in list)
    {

        this.DocumentChecklistMasterList.Insert(i,
            new RequestCheckListDetail  {
            Id = i,
            CheckListMaster = item
        });
        i++;
    }
```

None of these codes are working properly. 
I am still not able to add items to `DocumentChecklistMasterList`

Please help me:

EDIT:

IsObjectUsable() is extension method i have added to check if object is null

```
 public static bool IsObjectUsable(this object checkObject)
    {
        bool isUsable = true;

        if (checkObject == null || checkObject == DBNull.Value)
        {
            isUsable = false;
        }

        return isUsable;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but the list always shows count as "0"

Comment: How are you checking what values are in the list?

Comment: This line `ViewState["DocumentChecklistMasterList"].IsObjectUsable()` probably always returns `false`. Find out why.

Comment: I am simply debugging code using debugger point, and also binding the list to gridview

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244945/c-sharp-linq-listinterface-addrange-method-not-working ?

Comment: @DGibbs: you are right. It was returning false always. I just created new instance before adding items to it and it is working fine.